# Regex Avoid Unecessary Groups

Tags: python, regex

I have this code:

```
string = """a = 10 + 15
b = 50 + b
c = a + b
d = c + 50"""


letter = "([a-z])"
signs = "(\+|\-|\*|\/)"
regex = re.compile(r"{0} = (\d+) {1} (\d+)|"
                   r"{0} = (\d+) {1} {0}|"
                   r"{0} = {0} {1} {0}|"
                   r"{0} = {0} {1} (\d+)".format(letter, signs))signs))(\d+)".format(letter,signs))
```

If I do re.search(regex,string).groups() I end up with

```
('a', '10', '+', '15', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
(None, None, None, None, 'b', '50', '+', 'b', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'c', 'a', '+', 'b', None, None, None, None)
(None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'd', 'c', '+', '50')
```

But I want just 4 groups. [var,val1,operator,val2]

I'm using a list comprehension

```
[r for r in re.search(regex,string).groups() if r != None]
```

But I wonder if there's a way to do this in the regex itself.

Comment: What you need to do is surround your entire regex with `(?: ... ) so that it only captures one of the four groups instead of all of them.

Comment: I tried this still gives me 12 groups.

Comment: No, you need to make the regex all one string instead of using multiple strings, like `r'(?:{0} = (\d+) {1} (\d+)|{0} = (\d+) {1} {0}|{0} = {0} {1} {0}|{0} = {0} {1} (\d+))'`

Comment: In that case, it's probably best to simplify your regex so that it can be used for any scenario instead of using multiple `OR` symbols between full statements, such as `r'({0}) = (\d+|{0}) {1} (\d+|{0})', and change `letter = "([a-z])"` to `letter = "[a-z]"`

Comment: Oh, that actually work. You may post it as a answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Okay, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to simplify the regex from four separate statements to one slightly overloaded statement in this case, which does require modifying `letter`:

```
letter = "[a-z]"
signs = "(\+|\-|\*|\/)"
regex = re.compile(r"({0}) = (\d+|{0}) {1} (\d+|{0})".format(letter, signs))signs))(\d+)".format(letter,signs))
```

Comment: The only downside is that I can't use \d{1,2} for the regex because the format tries to change it(and fails).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?:...)` as a non-capturing group for things that need grouping, but not capturing. E.g.:

```
signs = "(?:\+|\-|\*|\/)"
```

However, you can get rid of plenty of them by just *not* making `signs` and `letter` groups in the first place:

```
letter = "[a-z]"
signs = "[+*/-]"
```

Comment: But I need to capture it.